# MariaDB: Remove Specific Link From Column

Tags: mysql

I recently detected on my cousin's blog a few click-jack links. I was alarmed because I immediately said to myself that I had some crappy adware on my browser... However I didn't. The links on the picture didn't even work.

On her computer and the links were working. I opened Chrome Extensions and there was some suspicious stuff there. After removing everything the links stopped working too.

I went to the database and saw this:

[image]

So apparently the Wordpress installation was not compromised and it was just the Chrome Extensions adding extra HTML to the post.

**My Question: Is there a way in SQL I can remove all those links?**

The ideia is to find the word `DiscountMan` and look for an anchor tag before that and the closing after and remove the tag, but leave the word on the middle intact.

```
<a class="garehbqm" title="Click to Continue &gt; by DiscountMan" href="#10518549"> lifestyle<img src="http://cdncache-a.akamaihd.net/items/it/img/arrow-10x10.png" alt=""></a>
```

The link and the image tag should be removed, however anything else inside the tag, like `lifestyle` (space before) should be kept.

Note: I can remove the `img` tag with this:

```
UPDATE table SET fieldname=REPLACE(fieldname,'<img src="http://cdncache-a.akamaihd.net/items/it/img/arrow-10x10.png" alt="">','');
```

But I don't know how to solve the link issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you Switch to MariaDB instead of MySQL? It has a REGEXP_REPLACE build-in. With it you can do a

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(fieldname, "(<a .* title=\\".*DiscountMan\\"[^>]*>)([^<]*)(<img [^>]*><\/a>)", '\\2')
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql/26179601#26179601).

You can test it on [enter link description here](http://regex101.com)

Comment: Thanks man! You rock, I had to do some changes since I already removed the images. Here is my final statement: `UPDATE table SET post_content=REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '(<a .* title=".*DiscountMan"[^>]*>)([^<]*)(<\/a>)', '\\2')`.